# Pan or zoom in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am trying to create some graphic matches on action (on either side of a transition, similar shapes are in the same place on the screen.

To accomplish this, I have an image with some targets which I would like to keep semi-transparent so that I can scale and move my footage underneath to precisely the right position.

I have considered pushing each clip into a separate plane on a separate screen, but I'm not sure how I would get a semi transparent overlay using this. Anyhow, it would be preferable to keep my edits within the VSE.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your asking. Would it work to adjust the *Opacity* in *Properties panel > edit strip*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. Go to *Add*  > *Effect Strip* > *Transform*, then right click on the element that you want to transform (i.e. the x offset) and select *Add Driver*. Now you will be able to pan/zoom dynamically and edit this change with keyframes on the graph screen.

Answer (score 3):

Not all values in the VSE can be driven with drivers. I am glad that this worked however for those values. Also there is a great addon for GUI editing of Transform values in the preview window. Check out a demo and link to script at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZpnkoEkY3E

Answer (score 1):

The current accepted solution will result in a lower resolution blurry image.

A better solution enable **Image Offset** for that video strip to have the video with a 1:1 pixel ratio (no re-scaling). Then adjust the offset X/Y and possibly add a transform effect strip to re-scale further.

Look at [Rescaling in the VSE yields low resloution, blurry images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42094/rescaling-in-the-vse-yields-low-resloution-blurry-images).