# How do I make a 2D image move smoothly across the screen in a video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am trying to make it so a 2D image simply slides across the screen in a video I am trying to make.  This isn't just one video, but many, as I have not yet found a solution to this problem... perhaps because I don't use Blender for a 3D Editor, I don't know.

If I try and take an image larger than my video output, regardless of the options I pick, the image is always cropped to the size of the video output.  So, if I have something that's 3k by 4k on a 1920*1080 video, the usable space is always 1920*1080.  Either the image is smooshed into the screen's resolution, or only a portion of the image can be used with Blender simply cropping off everything outside of the video resolution.

Quite separately, I tried to get around this issue by making multiple instances of 1920*1080 sections of the picture and having them move at the same rate next to each other as two or more different images.  For example, altering the X or Y on a Transform Strip for either of them and simply having them move at the same frames from their own Point A to Point B.  But, no matter what I do, the two images each seem to have their own "momentum", speeding up and slowing down as relating to something I can't wrap my head around.  They seem to build up to speed and then slow down when getting to their destination.  They do not move at a constant rate from Point A to Point B and so they create either a gap or overlap between them, usually both across the movement of the images.

So, if someone could help me, I'm looking for one of two solutions to do the same thing visually: 1) Have one large 2D image than I can pan around as no big deal which would be ideal, or 2) Instruct me how to make images moving across the screen move and a constant and even rate to achieve the same effect, rather than having them speed up and slow down.  Honestly, I have uses for both of those answers.

I'm new to Blender, at least for a year now, and essentially only know of it as a free Video Editor... so if the only way to do this is by using the 3D aspects of the program, I guess I would ask for links to a resource?  I'd like to keep myself in 2D if possible as my background is in drawing and video...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: somehow related:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42094/rescaling-in-the-vse-yields-low-resloution-blurry-images/42462#42462

Comment: For the second question, go to a graph editor and change the animation curves interpolation type to constant (I think via "T"), it's a Bezier curve by default which has this speed up and slow down.