# Superzoom effect in Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transforms

Obstacles seem to compound themselves to stop me from accomplishing it.

1. **How to pan the scene to find the target spot at a very high zoom?** Before I can set *Position: X, Y* values in *Transform* effect strip, I must find the target spot. However, once I set the desired *Scale* to a high value (150×), there is no obvious way to navigate (pan) the zoomed-in scene (either a *Movie* strip or an *Image* strip) in order to find the target spot. Output is cropped to the *Render Area* and zooming out by mouse fails to reveal neighbourhood outside the *Render Area.* Even if there is some way to turn off default cropping (please, let me know), GUI in the preview area is not responsive to panning by mouse. Trying to reverse the workflow by centering the scene to the target spot first (*Position: X, Y*), and setting *Scale* next, is a futile exercise because scaling doesn’t preserve *Position* values. (Changing the *Scale* value moves the target spot out of view despite unchanged *Position* values.) It’s even harder when the resolution is low because all I can see is a blob of interpolated pixels, so I can’t tell where I am and in which direction I should aim thence. (See screenshot.)[image]
2. **Why does exponential interpolation mode fail during superzoom?** By its nature, superzoom is an exponential process. But when the *Interpolation Mode* (in *Graph Editor*) for *Key Frames* based on *Scale* (in *Transform* effect strip) is set to anything other than basic modes (for example to *Sinusoidal* or *Exponential* rather than default *Bezier*), the result is so erratic that I must presume it’s a bug in Blender (version 2.74).
3. **How to align zooming-panning *Transform* interpolation curves of two different scene strips (each starting and ending at different time points) to accomplish coherent blending transition from one to another?** (From a low-resolution view to a high-resolution view in this particular case.)
4. <s>I can’t remember other obstacles at the moment. I may add them later.</s>

Should I split this question into four separate posts?

*Edit: 8 November 2016*

5. Stacking *Transform* filter on top of another *Transform* filter to solve some of the above issues results in transforming a strip cropped to the *Render Area* by the first filter instead of the full source material.
6. No one knows anything. It’s as if no one has ever produced a zoom effect in a video. It’s as if there are no Blender experts among the living and Blender had created itself alone. No one knows any other software that allows to get it done. No one even knows what’s wrong with my question. No one knows who else knows. Zooming in on a spot in a video: **rocket science.**

Comment: The VSE rescales any image to fill the dimensions of the scene. So any zoom you do there is only re-sampling this pre-scaled image. If you turn off that function per strip thn the VSE crops the image by the scene dimensions, so you can't scale the cropped sides back in. That might be why no-one has replied. Last time I needed to do this I just stacked the images as planes in 3D view and flew the camera over them. Alternatively you could use a UV pass from 3D view to remap images in the compositor.

Comment: @3pointedit: Rendering the camera flight over stacked 3D planes (each with a progressively higher degree of texture detail) to accomplish a superzoom effect – yes, I have tried it too. It works... but it takes 100× more CPU time. (Any ideas how to disable unnecessary rendering options? I have hoped to use the Blender Game engine because it’s supposed to work in real time. Sadly, when I switch to it, the options to produce a video file disappear...)

Comment: Oh you can absolutely export the viewport version using OpenGL render. Thats what the little clapper board icon at the bottom of the 3D view is for. Check out these great video tutorials for hacking the viewport https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rQlxcp9eeQ&list=PLMuVWx3uuscQsqt_PMdzAv45yomaUFbxz

Comment: @3pointedit: Fantastic! You’ve just opened up a whole new world of possibilities to me. If you want to post it as an answer (stacked 3D planes + camera flight + viewport rendering), I will mark it as a solution. It’s a workaround really, since it doesn’t solve any of the described issues, but it’s a very powerful workaround – and it accomplishes the end goal of an animated superzoom video scene in Blender. It’s even more useful than a proper solution would be. Meanwhile, if anyone else finds proper solutions to the described issues at a later time, it’s good too – I will upvote them too.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of answers after 18 hours and meagre 12 views, I’ll start building my own answer – block by block.

1. **How to locate target spot on a strip at a very high zoom?**
   Reverse your workflow by centering the strip on target spot first, but begin at a manageable *Scale.* Then multiply *Scale* and *Position* (or *Position* shift value if initial *Position* wasn’t zero) by exactly the same factor. Fine-tune *Position* if you can. If you can’t, undo last multiplication and redo it using a smaller factor. Repeat until you reach the desired *Scale.*

   - a) **How to disable cropping of the output to the *Render Area* in the preview window?**
     — (Impossible?)
   - b) **How to pan a strip in the preview area?**
     <s>(Impossible?)</s> Impossible!
2. **Why does exponential interpolation mode fail during superzoom?**
   Buggy Blender? Workaround: approximate desired interpolation curves manually using multiple linear interpolation segments.
3. **How to align interpolation curves of different strips?**

   No relevant functionality in Blender. Workaround: approximate desired interpolation curves manually using multiple linear interpolation segments.

*Edit: 8 November 2016*

5. **Leave it.** I’ll sooner make it manually in C (programming language) than in Blender + StackExchange. Literally.

### Interesting links

- [“Rescaling in the VSE yields low resloution, blurry images”](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42094/rescaling-in-the-vse-yields-low-resloution-blurry-images)
- [“How do I prevent VSE strips using Image Offset from being cropped before the transform effect can shrink them onto the screen?”](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47795/how-do-i-prevent-vse-strips-using-image-offset-from-being-cropped-before-the-tra)
- [“VSE. I need to rotate image with arbitrary center pivot point that is not in the center of the image”](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53094/vse-i-need-to-rotate-image-with-arbitrary-center-pivot-point-that-is-not-in-the)
- [“§11. Blender Video Editing (Importing Images [Overlay/Resize/Rotate])”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_dy4yMSJSw) (YouTube)

Comment: I can understand your frustration with the VSE but honestly its the wrong tool for this task. What was wrong with rendering OpenGL 3D view?

Comment: @3pointedit: Nothing wrong, it works perfectly. Ordinary rendering is 100× too slow for this job and I didn’t know that Blender allowed using 3D view for video rendering until [you showed me how](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66637/superzoom-effect-in-video-sequence-editor/66690?noredirect=1#comment138791_66637).

Comment: @3pointedit: Oh, this question “was bumped to the homepage by Community♦ 16 hours ago”. So that’s why you are asking me what’s wrong 3D view rendering. I didn’t bump it though. I only haven’t selected any answer as a solution. That’s why Community♦ bumps it. I wish I could select your comment as a solution but I can’t. Someone must convert it to an answer for that.

Comment: Fair enuf. I will try to work it up into a proper answer with examples then ;-)

Comment: @3pointedit: There is no hurry. I already know the solution from your comment, so post it only if you want to. The question has scored 0 votes, so it’s not like you’ll earn massive reputation from answering it anyway.

Comment: Looking into it, I found out that the "Import Planes As Images" addon, will actually construct drivers from the 3D view. You can't scale and move images in the compositor much faster than in 3D view. So I can simply line up the images in 3D view and animate the camera all using the textured view render. But perform the actual mix in the compositor. Very fast :D