# Zoom and Crop of a video already recorded

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to use Blender for editing sports videos. I need to show players specific movements they did wrong or right. I am wondering if there is a way to zoom in once I have already recorded the video?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42094/2843

Answer (score 3):

You can select your video strip and add a *Effect strip/Transform*. In the params, you have a *scale* parameter and a *position* parameter

[image: set scale and position of your video strip]

Comment: This will probably result in the magnified image being a little blurry but that is unavoidable.