# How to edit vertical Video in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I add video (shot in verticle mode) in VSE the video shows horizontal 
[image]

Change put put resolution to vertical frame **Height 1280** px **Width 720** px
[image]

Add effects Strip **Transform** and input **Rotation** value **-90** degrees

> But the result is not intended
>   [image]

Then i do some **Aproximate non unoform scaling** which i dont think is technically right and **not precise**
[image]

**

> Is there any other more intuitive and precise way to edit Vertical videos?

**

Comment: You could do the transformation in [AviSynth "on the fly"](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843) before importing your footage into Blender...

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42462/2843

Comment: @Samoth thank you the link was informative but does not deal with video. But yes with still and image sequence it is great piece of information.

Comment: This video worked for me https://youtu.be/hfo-DRGvkgo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Indirect Method**

I named the scene as **Video_1_comp**

Go to **VSE** (Video Sequence Editor) and add movie

[image]

Select Only Video Strip in VSE and Strip Menu > Set Render Size

[image]

Go to the End of the Video Clip hover cursor on **Timeline** and **press E** to set End Frame

[image]

Result of all above steps
Resolution, Frame Range, Frame Rate are set to the Source Video's settings

[image]

**NOW DELETE THE VIDEO and AUDIO tracks**

**Go to Compositing Screen**
**Add > Input > MovieClip**

Add **Rotate node** and input Value **-90** it could be 90 for some videos
**Don't use Back Drop preview it is not correct even though output render is correct**

[image]

Then create a **new scene** with **Copy Settings** i named it as **Edit**

[image]

Then go to Video Sequence editor Screen

**Add > Scene... >** choose the Scene in my case **Video_1_comp**

Set Render Resolution resolution to vertical frame **Height Y:1280** px **Width X:720** px

Go to 3D view **Properties** if its not showing already **press n**

Scroll down to find **OpenGL Preview** and **un-check** it

Now add the Same Movie clip source again on top of existing strip

But this time **Mute/delete** the **Video** strip and keep the audio

[image]

> Now you can edit it like any movie clip you would have edited

Answer (score 1):

Intuitive: Using [VSE Transform Addon](https://github.com/kgeogeo/VSE_Transform_Tools).

- Change Render Size resolution (interchange width with height)
- Download and install it
- Select strip, press T (special transform effect is created)
- In preview, press R (rotate), press 90.
- Press S (scale) and scale it to render size. Zoom to any border (eg: upper-left), scale it again for precise.

Precise:

- Use one of the methods: the one you wrote or the one I wrote above (with VSE Transform Addon).
- Do a simple math: if movie is Full-HD, do:
- 1920 / 1080 = 1,77777777778
- 1080 / 1920 = 0,5625
- Now, use these results to the X and Y scale in Transform effect, respectively.

Example (I use a well-rotated to make a rotated video):

[image]