# Image offset only applies to single frame and not to metastrip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I put a series of images in the Video Editor but they get scaled to fit the render size. To prevent that i click "Image offset" and that puts the original dimensions back. However it only does it for a single image frame.
If I metastrip the image sequence and apply "Image offset" to it, the dimensions are not brought back.

So I would need to apply the option to every single frame manually....very inconvenient.....is there some command to apply the setting to every selected frame?

Note: I tried scaling up the strip to the correct ratio, but i notice a signficant loss in Image quality, when comparing 2 identical strips with the 2 techniques..the Image offset retains the frame detail, while scaling up degrades the image..

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42094/rescaling-in-the-vse-yields-low-resloution-blurry-images/42462#42462

Comment: Thanks, but thats only related to the secondary part of my post. There some good info, but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: that is the very reason is better to ask only one question. Different questions should be asked in separate posts.

Comment: Actually you can use a built in function. Try this solution to a similar problem http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61731/vse-channels-volume

Answer (score 3):

You will need to activate a Sequencer addon, that comes included with the official Blender download. 
***Extra Sequencer Actions*** https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Sequencer/Extra_Sequencer_Actions

Change one image to the Offset value you want, then select all the other images and include the changed image last, eg. shift right-click to make this last one active.

Go down to the Strip Menu in the VSE timeline and select Copy Properties > Input - Image Offset

[image: Copy VSE properties]

Now all of the other images will inherit the setting from the active strip.

Comment: Look very promising...but I didn't find it in the official installation..

Comment: Hmm, thats odd. I thought that it was the official distribution.