# VSE channel's volume

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, audio

Helo,
can't figure out how to change the volume of multiple strips or one separate channel.
i have a video with multiple audio channels, one for background music, one for audio effects, and one for narrating. i have to rise the volume of all the narrating channel - it's a lot of strips, it's already after editing (the audio editing was made in blender as well).
maybe some plugin or atleast already exist that i can't find on the web.
thanx for any help.

Comment: Maybe an adjustment Layer might help you out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The volume of an audio strip can be changed in the sound properties panel which you can find in the sequencer's properties region - press <kbd>N</kbd>

[image: sound properties]

To alter multiple strips, select them and adjust the volume then right click on the volume and select *Copy To Selected*

Comment: THNX a lot! didn't thought about the "copy to selected"...

Comment: It was very helpful!

Comment: Still, isn't change the volume of the channel is a so basic feature in a video editor?

Comment: That was how it was done years ago and no-one has offered a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.76 and later you can actually use another VSE sequence as a source. You could edit all of you music or sound as required then select them all and create a metastrip. Then copy the metasrtip to another scene VSE timeline. Mute the original (but keep it incase you want to make further edits), and replace it with the other scene's strip. Then in its properties activate "USE SEQUENCE". This will give you a mix down and control of master volume for all of the strips that you copied. Sadly you cannot change channel balance here for panning effects.

[image: VSE mixdown audio]