# Is it possible to disable auto-scale/fit of the backdrop in the video sequence editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'd like to be able to view the backdrop at 1:1 scale like the sequencer view or control the backdrop in a similar way to the node editor (don't see the option to in the Properties panel).

Gif showing Image Offset doesn't seem to help (neither does Crop). All it seems to do is offset the image or shrink it if rendering only a percentage of the resolution. This is with Blender reset to defaults btw. What I would like is the image to stay 500px no how I resize the area/panel.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting _Strip Input > Image Offset_? With that option checked, it should at least display 1:1 even though some parts might get cropped. Otherwise I recommend the velvet addon, which can add a transform to scale the image correctly.

Comment: Nope, I don't get 1:1 or even any cropping with Image Offset. It does shrink the backdrop if the resolution in the render settings is set to less than 100% but it's not at it's real size and still shrinks/enlarges depending on the panel's size. I'll checkout the addon.

Comment: Upload your files, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Not sure where to upload it? Also you can just see this by adding any scene to the sequence editor, enabling backdrop, and then resizing the panel -> image scale changes, Image Offset and Cropping do not help.

Comment: Can't reproduce, sorry. Could you add a screenshot showing the problem? Are you using the latest release?

Comment: I have added a gif showing what I mean. Tried with latest, no difference.

Comment: Read this related link: [Rescaling in the VSE yields low resloution, blurry images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42094/rescaling-in-the-vse-yields-low-resloution-blurry-images/42462#42462)

Comment: @cegaton Well now I know not to ever do that, but not sure how it's supposed to help. I'm not using transforms or anything.
For now I got an old second monitor and I'm duplicating the VSE to it and setting it to preview mode which does allow 1:1 Zoom. But that's kind of a pain. I wish I could just edit over the backdrop. The reason I want this btw, is that the scaling messes with thin lines and I'm using freestyle and sometimes it's hard to tell if part of a line is drawn wrong or it's just the way the scaling is interpolated. There isn't some way to change this either is there?

Comment: The whole background timeline preview thing is a bit of a hack from an earlier Open Movie project. So I wouldn't be surprised if it "lacks" features. I expect that it dynamically scales to always fit the view. Try making a smaller window set to 1:1 but small enough to show only a portion of the whole screen, then pan it around. Us another preview window for an overview, or "fit" shot.