# 1920 x 1080 res to 1080 x 1080 res

Tags: dimensions

I'm taking a video I made for youtube in 1920 x 1080 that I want to fit formats on intagram which are 1080 x 1080. I've taken the video rendered at 1920 x 1080 an dropped into a blender sesson set at 1080 x 1080. I've then shrunk down the video. so I am left with a gap and a chunk of the frame from the 1920x 1080 chopped off.

Heres a screen shot[image]. I hope this problem is clear? Im expecing to have the 1920 x 1080 to maintain its ratio and for there to be gaps at the top and bottom?

thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to use a larger video in a smaller project you will discover some serious design flaws in the video sequence editor. I'd advise you to do the transform with the compositor.

Comment: uh oh, i haven't use the compositor before. what do I do here?

Comment: In your transform strip properties set the Scale to 1.0x0.55. Works for me with a 1920x1080 source video and Blender set to 1080x1080 and rendered to video fine.

Comment: @ rob I tried the transform but I was hoping to illustrate in the screenshot that despite scale the screen blender and lopped off part of the original frame, its just not there? edit I see what you mean....that will work for now thats very much!!...it would be good it work out the ration so you don't how to judge the scalling?

Comment: You can do this in the VSE. Use image offset, and then resize. Read: [Rescaling in the VSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42094/rescaling-in-the-vse-yields-low-resloution-blurry-images/42462#42462)