# How to resample a video clip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have 30fps, 1440dpi car Dashcam footage but desired action is far away. Would like to resample to 720 or 360dpi 30fps, w/o loss of pixels & only use part of resulting video (crop?) that contains action.

Searched resample & zoom but couldn't understand if any applied to my situation.

Comment: So you want to crop the video and let the result be the total width/height for the output video?

Comment: Yes. I want to zoom (resample?) so the desired action is in the forefront. Have that take up most of the width/height of video & remove (crop?) the insignificant excess surrounding the action. IOW, as if the camera was closer to the action.

Answer (score 1):

Load your video clip into VSE (I'm using an image here, but it is the same for videos)

[image: VSE High res]

Set the resolution to your output requirements.

Add an **Effects Strip -> Transform**

Change the **Scale** parameters and recenter with the **Position X/Y**

[image: Resampled]

Render output resampled.

I spent sometime trying the **Clip** options in the **Transform** strip but they did not work when changing the output resolution.

Comment: Tried your method, (thanks for suggestion), but moving X & Y distorted frame, not moving w/in image. Having some luck w/ transform effect. Will post when finished testing w/ what, if anything worked.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42094/rescaling-in-the-vse-yields-low-resloution-blurry-images