# Manual video stablizing

Tags: video

I have a shoot some footage of a firefly standing still on a wall at night and blinking every half a second or so. The result is very shaky including some sharp pan movements. Its mostly very dark with just the blinking spots visible.

If I could center the video over the blinking spot it might look nice.

Its possible for me to use a transform effect strip, and create position keyframes at the blinks in order to center them throughout the video.
However, creating position frames in that way isnt very intuitive, and requires entering X and Y values manually.

So I wondered if instead of using the transform effect layer it would be easier to somehow use manual tracking with a marker in the Video Clip Editor. 
I tried it but didnt know how to create keyframes for my manually positioned marker (keyframes are auto created when Im using the "track selected markers"). What parameter/channel should I highlight in order to create a keyframe? Is there a better method for doing this task?

Comment: In the Movie Clip Editor, you can create keyframes on a tracker by just moving it. Use the G key and position the tracker where you want. A key frame will be created automatically.

Comment: Watch the wonderful [Track, Match, Blend!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df3TAZ-VNso&index=4&list=PLtuvwW4VAp5tu2RdbRHThM6FVFfvFur1g) tutorials... ;-)

Comment: @cegaton Pressing G and re-positioning the tracker does add a keyframe (I see a yellow dot on the MCE time bar) but when I move one frame back, the tracker jumps to the previous position without any ease/interpolation although previous keyframe is 20 frames back.

Comment: @Samoth Thanks for this amazing tutorial, but I couldnt find a way to manually use the tracker, it demonstrate how to track using the auto search buttons.

Comment: It's a playlist, so start after the intro for more explanation. He tracks markers more manually in the part 13 about blurry footage and I think he explains the manual process somewhere more detailled before using the auto track feature. But your question stays a bit unclear about the exact type of your footage so you might improve this description or include some examples to get some more specific help. After manually tracking a marker you can convert it into an empty

Comment: @Samoth I have edited the description, hope its clearer now. I learned a lot from the blurry footage tutorial but manual tracking takes place only after using the "track marker" buttons, when some track has been automatically calculated.

Comment: I think it would be really helpful if you could upload at least a part of your footage to a video platform and maybe share a non-public link?
As far as I know the MCE, you need to have a frame by frame tracking without interpolation in between though...

Comment: Its probably best to do this job in the Video Sequence Editor. Using a transform effect layer I just create keyframes and manually position each blink in the center of the frame. Also found out about a nice addon called ["VSE Transform Addon"](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2906/22924) that makes manual positioning easier.