# How to use a driver to pan and zoom an image

Tags: video-sequence-editor, drivers

I am trying to follow this answer: [Pan or zoom in the VSE (accepted answer)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2862/112363%3E)

After I right click on `x offset` and select `Add driver`, the x offset turns purple. I am not sure how to see the graph screen or how to add keyframes as suggested in the answer.

How does one see the graph screen, and add keyframes (So I can animate the x-offset of a photo to get  a pan and zoom effect)? Could someone please provide some more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you should be using a driver OR you should be using keyframes - not both since one will override the other. It sounds like you should actually be using keyframes - so right-click and Remove Driver.

Using keyframes the field should be yellow/orange/green to indicate the keyframe. Move to your frame, set the value, then hit ‘i’ to insert keyframe. No need for driver.

Comment: Im in the `Sequencer`, and press `i`, but no keyframe is inserted. I can't find `insert keyframe` in the menus either.

Comment: You need to hover over the field (Position X or Position Y) before pressing 'I'. At newer versions of Blender there is also a dot/diamond toggle alongside which you can click. Right-clicking the field should give you 'Insert Keyframe' although if there is already a keyframe then you'll have 'Replace Keyframe' and 'Delete Keyframe' options instead.